# Can you "dumb down" ES6 template strings to normal strings?

Tags: javascript, localization, ecmascript-6, gettext, template-strings

I have to work around the limitation of `gettext` to recognise ES6 template strings, and I thought about getting the "non interpolated value" of the template strings as a compilation step, in order to have only "normal" strings in the code.

Basically what I would like to achieve is transform this

```
const adjective = 'wonderful'
const something = `Look, I am a ${adjective} string`

console.log(something)
> "Look, I am a wonderful string"
```

into this

```
const adjective = 'wonderful'
const something = 'Look, I am a ${adjective} string'

console.log(something)
> "Look, I am a ${adjective} string"
```

One brutal way of achieving this is using `sed`, but it's most certainly not the more elegant (and probably also error prone)

```
sed "s/\`/'/g" FILENAME
```

Any better and cleaner idea comes to mind?

Comment: No, you can't "dumb down" a template string without losing the "smart" properties (which include string expansion). Notice that ``(`A ${b=alert()}`)`` will execute `alert()`, which won't happen with `'A ${b=alert()}'`

Comment: I know that. I don't need the smartness in `gettext`, since it is not smart enough to understand template strings. (I have clarified even more my question)

Comment: Are you just asking about the string interpolation, or do you need template tags as well?

Comment: Have you tried a transpiler like babel?

Comment: the transpiler is not a viable option because translation strings are wrapped in a function that gets transformed as well. E.g. `t('translate me')` becomes something like `function(par, 0)('translate me')`, which `gettext` doesn't understand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great question. There are four solutions that come to mind:

#### 1. Brute force

A brute force replacement of backticks with quote marks prior to scanning for translatable strings, as you suggested, is not a horrible idea, as long as you understand the risks. For instance, consider:

```
"hello, this word is in `backticks`"
```

Another edge case is

```
`${`I am nested`}`
```

This approach will also break multi-line template strings.

#### 2. Fix `xgettext`

Of course, the "correct" solution is to write a fork of `xgettext` that deals with template strings. Then you could just write

```
const something = _(`Look, I am a ${adjective} string`);
```

Unfortunately, this could be harder that it seems. There is a bunch of hard-wired logic inside xgettext related to strings. If you were to undertake this project, many would thank you.

#### 3. Using a parser

The more robust alternative is to use a JavaScript parser such as Esprima. These parsers expose the ability to pick up tokens (such as template strings). As you can see at http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html, the relevant token type to look for is `TemplateLiteral`.

#### 4. Unadvisable hacks

Another (bad?) idea is to write template strings as regular strings to start with, then treat them as template strings at run-time. We define a function `eval_template`:

```
const template = _("Look, I am a ${adjective} string");
const something = eval_template(template, {adjective});
```

`eval_template` converts a string into an evaluated template. Any variable in local scope used in the template string needs to be provided to `eval_template` as part of the object passed in the second parameter (because functions created using `Function` are in the global scope and cannot access local variables, so we have to pass them in). It is implemented as follows:

```
function eval_template_(s, params) {
  var keys = Object.keys(params);
  var vals = keys.map(key => params[key]);

  var f = Function(...keys, "return `" + s + "`");
  return f(...vals);
}
```

Granted, this is a bit awkward. The only advantage of this approach is that it requires no pre-scan rewriting.

Minor point, but if the original template string is multi-line, you cannot directly rewrite it as a regular string. In that case, you can leave it as a back-ticked template string but escape the `$` as `\$`, and all will be well:

Bottom line: unless you want to rewrite `xgettext`, use a parser, or engage in other hackery, do the brute force replacement.

Comment: Instead of all that, you can do ``t => Function('return `' + t + '`')()``. Hope it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, because unlike `eval`,  functions defined using the Function constructor are in the global scope, and cannot access the variables such as `adjective`.

Comment: Good point. Very good point indeed. There must be an eaeier way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am working on a localization solution that is based on es6 template literals. You can check out it here - https://c-3po.js.org. This project has extraction functionality (based on the babel plugin). And also you can use it to build localized js. Here is how it looks like:

```
t`Hello ${name}`
```

Comment: That is surprisingly similar to what I've done here: https://github.com/dmatteo/crusca-cli