# Es6 nested backticks to interpolate variable's template substitutions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a string loaded from a file in node.js without success.

The file contains template substitutions like: ${js-stuff}, which I want to resolve in the scope of whenever I evaluate the variable within the backticks.

I'm calling the string which contains the text loaded from the file 'template'.

I hoped `` console.log(`${template}`) `` would recursively resolve the template substitutions inside the template variable and print the result, but it seems as if I'm wrong as only the template-string get's printed out without it's template substitutions being resolved.

As the string interpolation doesn't work recursively, I would have to do something like ``` console.log(``${template}``) ```, but I'm not quite sure how.

Using the eval function I got it working like this:

```
console.log(eval(`\`${template}\``));
```

But this doesn't seem like the best way to do this?

TDLR;
I don't want to evaluate a single variable using string interpolating, I want to evaluate a variable which contains a string consisting of a template substitution.

Comment: Are you preforming the `console.log` within loaded Javascript or in the actual console itself?

Comment: `require('vm')` .. will help u .. best regards

Comment: Template literals are compile-time things, there's no way to evaluate them apart from calling the js compiler, i.e. `eval`

Comment: Another good resource is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882100/can-you-dumb-down-es6-template-strings-to-normal-strings/34883543#34883543.