# Template literal trapped in a string variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I have a template `Hello, ${user.name}` stored in a variable. I am reading this from an external file using `fs.read`.

Now, obviously when I attach to the innerHTML of a target div, it shows the string as it is and not "Hello, James" (assuming user.name = James) as intended.
Is there a way to make it happen?

extfile.txt => 
`` {"A":"`Welcome, ${user.name}`"} ``

Node.js code =>

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/extfile.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  } else {
    let x = JSON.parse(data);
    socket.emit('var',x.A);
  }
});
```

HTML =>

```
socket.on('var',function(x)){
  getElementById('target').innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: You use the character ` for template literals, not "

Comment: What template mechanism are you using? JavaScript template literals? If so, it'd be `Hello, ${user.name}` and it will not work because template literals are compile-time, not run-time.

Comment: @cartant "Compile time"? JS is interpereted... template arguments are evaluated every time the template literal is evaluated

Comment: @rookie Can you show us more complete JS/HTML that demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Comment: @qxz Fair point. Interpretation-time, then. The issue is that template literals are just that: literals. You cannot use strings stored in variables.

Comment: I am using the default JavaScript template literal.

Comment: @cartant The point of template literals is that they can substitute dynamic data... See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edbp7jdf/)

Comment: @rookie Can you give us an idea of the broader feature you're trying to implement? Perhaps [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41071779/edit) to show us your current complete code?

Comment: @qxz Yes, I am aware of that, but the OP's first sentence states that the template is stored in a *variable* and that is the problem. It is not a template *literal*.

Comment: That's fair. I am reading a json from an external file. {"A":"`Hello, ${user.name}"}. Let x = (JSON from the file). Now when I document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = x.A, I expected it to substitute the user.name from an existing variable. It did not do it. How can I make that happen. PS: Please, Ignore the typos/error, typing from a phone and not my workstation.

Comment: @cartant hi, have edited the question to include the code showing what i am precisely doing. Am still stuck. Thanks in advance. I am open to any alternate way of looking to the problem as well.

Comment: This question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882100/can-you-dumb-down-es6-template-strings-to-normal-strings/34883543#34883543

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've slightly rewritten a solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882100/can-you-dumb-down-es6-template-strings-to-normal-strings/34883543#34883543).

Here, `eval_template` evaluates an ES6 template string provided as a regular string. Any variable in local scope used in the template string needs to be provided as a property of the object passed in the second parameter (because functions created using `Function` are in the global scope and cannot access local variables).

This is perilously close to using `eval`. You might want to choose a different approach to handling your template strings. ES6 template strings are designed to be a run-time mechanism to create string literals, not a templating language whose templates can be stored and re-used.

```js
function eval_template(s, params) {
  return Function(...Object.keys(params), "return " + s)
    (...Object.values(params));
}

const template = "`Welcome, ${user.name}`";
console.log(eval_template(template, {user: {name: "James"}}));
```

There is no reason this could not be used with a tagged template string, as long as the tag is passed in as a parameter:

```
eval_template("tag`${boo}`", {tag, boo});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem sometimes when I have my labels variables in another file, and those labels should have a template literal. I this cases I usually use a workaround to simulate this behaviour (take this code as a guide :D )

labels.js:

```
export default:{
    labelWithSpeudoliteral: "text to {{change}}"
}
```

MyHelper.js:

```
    generateLiteral(s, params) {
        const entries = Object.entries(params);
        let sentence = s;
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
                const literal = `{{${entry[0]}}}`
                sentence = sentence.replace(literal, entry[1]);
            }
        )
        return sentence;
    }
```

Now in my code I use this helper the following way:

```
console.log(generateLiteral(labels.labelWithSpeudoliteral, {'change': 'literal'})
```

And the result of the label should be:

```
text to literal
```

As you can see using the {{ }} symbols as marks, generateLiteral() use them and the params received to change the text value with the template literal. It is not the best way, but I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Template literals need a `$`, not an ampersand. Also, remember to use backticks and not quotes.