# An object with string templates

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create an object with string templates in it. How do I do that? If I use double quotes for the message -- see below -- I'm not getting a template. If I use back-ticks, I'm getting an error.

```
const templates = {
   "hello": {message: `Hello ${name}!`},
   "price": {message: `How much is this ${product}?`}
}
```

The idea is to return a custom message that looks something like this. The code below is not complete but you'll get the idea.

```
const getMessage = (type, name, product) => {
   const message = templates[type].message;
   return message;
}
```

Comment: Your first code already works.

Comment: The suspense is killing me... what's the error!?

Comment: @Gothodo : it is not duplicated

Comment: The error is Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined. This is in the templates object.

Comment: Do I need to pass name, product to the templates object for it to work? How would I even do that?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI You're going to have to be more specific about why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071779/template-literal-trapped-in-a-string-variable/41073463#41073463 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882100/can-you-dumb-down-es6-template-strings-to-normal-strings/34883543#34883543.

Comment: Fundamentally the easiest fix would be to make your template object contain functions that accept the variables and return a string. As it is now, the template is resolved into a string at the moment the templates object is created, at which point none of that context exists.